# Ng-Bootstrap Toast header display conditionally

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular15

I'm working with Ng-Boostrap in Angular 15 and I'm trying to display the header of my toast in a conditional manner, depending on whether I'm passing any text to be displayed (it should show the header) or not (it should hide the header).

My toast component is something like this:

```js
<ngb-toast *ngFor="let toast of toastService.toasts"
    (hidden)="toastService.remove(toast)">
    <ng-template ngbToastHeader *ngIf="toast.header">
        <div class="me-auto">
            <fa-icon [icon]="getIcon(toast)" [fixedWidth]="true" size="lg"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<strong>{{toast.header}}</strong>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    {{toast.message}}
</ngb-toast>
```

The problem at this point is that the `*ngIf` conflicts with the `ng-template` and breaks the template and it's never shown until I remove the `*ngIf`.

What would be the right way to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

The official [doc](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#prefer-the-asterisk--syntax) says:

> Angular creates an `<ng-template>` element and applies the `*ngIf` directive onto it where it becomes a property binding in square brackets, `[ngIf]`. The rest of the `<div>`, including its class attribute, is then moved inside the `<ng-template>`:

So you should try:

```
<ngb-toast *ngFor="let toast of toastService.toasts"
    (hidden)="toastService.remove(toast)">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="toast.header">
        <div class="me-auto" ngbToastHeader>
            <fa-icon [icon]="getIcon(toast)" [fixedWidth]="true" size="lg"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<strong>{{toast.header}}</strong>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    {{toast.message}}
</ngb-toast>
```

Otherwise, you can try to encapsulate your `ng-template` inside a `<ng-container>`

```
<ngb-toast *ngFor="let toast of toastService.toasts"
    (hidden)="toastService.remove(toast)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="toast.header">
       <ng-template ngbToastHeader>
        <div class="me-auto">
            <fa-icon [icon]="getIcon(toast)" [fixedWidth]="true" size="lg"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<strong>{{toast.header}}</strong>
        </div>
       </ng-template>
     </ng-container>
    {{toast.message}}
</ngb-toast>
```

Comment: I had already tried both approaches but without success: the one with the `ng-template` and the `[ngIf]` directive renders the header twice, so I get the same header inside the body section; then the one with the `ng-container` and the `*ngIf` just doesn't render anything. I'm pretty sure this is some sort of incompatibility with the `ngbToastHeader` directive, but I can't seem to find a workaround.

Comment: BTW, here is a stackblitz sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-beqqag

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-beqqag-efewys?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoast-custom-header.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftoast-custom-header.ts, is it fixing it ? It seems

Comment: Not really, because it's rendering the template of the header inside the body section of the toast, not as the real header. You can tell the difference because it lacks the division between both sections and the close button (X) to the right of the header text. Unfortunately, this is the same behavior I've been achieving and what I'm trying to find a fix/workaround.